# shopify embedded app hmac verification failed php

Tags: php, shopify

Hi shopify guru's I know this question has come around a thousand times, I know this because I have read every single thread I could find.

My app verificaton was working fine, but now that I switched to embedded app, I can't seem to verify the hmac.

```
    //Remove hmac from hash comparison
    $hmac = $data['hmac'];
    unset($data['hmac']);

    //sort the values alphabetically
    ksort($data);
    $data = urldecode(http_build_query($data));

    $hash = hash_hmac('sha256', $data, $this->ci->get('settings')['shopify']['api_secret']);
```

This code will keep returning a different hash from the hmac shopify sends me, I'm guessing there is a problem with encoding or escaping, I have tried every thing I could think of (htmlspecialchars, urldecode, strreplace, doublecheck secret etc..)

the string looks like this after the urldecode line:

locale=en&protocol=https://&shop=mystorehandle.myshopify.com&timestamp=1539901099

Any help would be appreciated, I wanted to get some work done on my app, but the past 3 hours have been filled with trying to get my hmac in sync with shopify's :(

I'm quiet certain I'm doing it right, but have no clue as to why it won't work then.

I'm buying a pie for whoever knows the answer first
.

Comment: What Shopify recipe are you following? They have a couple, and there are errors in the docs too... webhooks authentication differs from the oAuth, and app proxies too. Unless you provide more details, it is hard to help you.

Comment: https://help.shopify.com/en/api/getting-started/authentication/oauth#verification This one, its quite confusing which one I need, shopify should add a few test hmac and test strings to verify correct implementation

Comment: As a matter of fact, when I try to get the hmac from the documentation my code succeeds :(

Comment: A more detailed post with a test url where i calculate hmac: https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/partners-technical/t/embedded-app-hmac-verification-fails-546265

Comment: Here is where it get's freaky, this is the secret from my development app, when I try this hashing and code on the live app it works as expected, so somehow the development secret app key is not in sync with shopify (this is the only thing I can contemplate, I have already lost too much time on this, so I will do some more research after I get this done, but hey CAKE FOR ME TOMORROW! :) ) thanks for your input @DavidLazar

Comment: I'm having this same problem. Code used to work. Now my PROD app is failing, but TEST app is fine. Same code. Secret keys are definitely correct. Something weird is going on. Please update me if you get it working!

Comment: The only difference I can see between my TEST app (working) and PROD app (not working) are that TEST app sends down parameters in the order: hmac/locale/protocol/shop/timestamp whereas PROD app (broken) sends down parameters in the order: hmac/shop/timestamp/protocol/locale

Answer (score 1):

Ok so... don't ask me how or why this works, but it does. After 2-3 hours on this, I took a complete stab in the dark, and it worked. I'm pretty sure it only works because there is a bug on the Shopify side.

My embedded app was being fed GET params hmac/shop/timestamp/protocol/locale in that order.

For some reason, building a query string of shop=[myshop]&timestamp=[timestamp] worked.

In other words, I removed hmac, but ALSO protocol and locale.

Using this code though, BROKE the TEST version of my app, which was actually working fine with protocol and locale included.

My only conclusion here is that the hmac is derived from the GET parameters following hmac, which are in alphabetical order, stopping when the following parameter is not in that order.

So if GET params are hmac/shop/timestamp/protocol/locale - generate your hash string using shop & timestamp.

If GET params are hmac/locale/protocol/shop/timestamp - generate your hash string using locale, protocol, shop & timestamp.

So strange. Would be really interested to know if this works for you also!

Here's my code:

```
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $queryStringArray);
$providedHmac = $_GET['hmac'];

unset($queryStringArray['hmac']);
$amp = '';
$i = 0;
foreach($queryStringArray as $key => $value)
{
    $keyFirstLetter = substr($key, 0, 1);
    if($i == 0 || $keyFirstLetter > $lastKeyFirstLetter)
    {
        $newQueryString .= $amp . $key . '=' . $value;
        $amp = '&';
    }
    $lastKeyFirstLetter = $keyFirstLetter;
    $i++;
}

$calculatedHmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $newQueryString, SHOPIFY_APP_SHARED_SECRET);

$hmacValid = false;
if($calculatedHmac == $providedHmac)
{
    $hmacValid = true;
}
```

Comment: Hi, happy to see I'm not the only one, sorry :). I will try out your code with my 'old' app which stopped working. 

Can you double check on your dev and production app when your secret key was generated? the only major difference I can see in my apps is that the 'old' DEV app, which stopped working it's secret key it says: "Created over 1 year ago"

Comment: PROD app which stopped working had a key which was generated 4 months ago

Comment: I confirm, this worked for me, any news about HMAC changes from Shopify?

Comment: @ThomasLang How did you go? Any luck?